# Should the leaders of Jewish organisations be elected or appointed?

Tags: tzibur-community, organizations, voting

Organisations, including synagogues, are set up by people with common interests or concerns.

As such organisations develop, they need to provide for their future leadership.

Are there sources that require that members **vote** to provide the leadership of the organisation?

Another way would be for the original founding committee to **appoint** the new leadership.

Comment: Many Shul's are opened by the Rav himself. I think every Shul can have their own by-laws and there is no one standard.

Comment: @GershonGold .. but is there a system with more inherent value? Churchill said, "Democracy is the worst form of government, except for all those other forms that have been tried from time to time." (from a House of Commons speech on Nov. 11, 1947)